# How to load data using thread in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, .net-4.0

First of all, I am using .Net framework 4, therefore, I can't use Async/Await yet (Yea, I know, I should upgrade to vs 2013).

Anyway, please take a look at the following simple code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
            {
                model.ItemsToDisplay = SlowProcessList();
            };

        return View(model);
    }

    public static List<string> SlowProcessList()
    {
        List<string> strList = new List<string>();

        strList.Add("First Item");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        strList.Add("Second Item");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        strList.Add("Third Item");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        return strList;
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ItemsToDisplay)
{
    <p>@item</p>
}
```

As you can see, I want to return the view first, and then load the data on the background and display it on the form when available. Can anyone guide me to the right direction of doing so?

I'm thinking the proper way to approach this is by: Making a Ajax call on PageLoad and wait for that response.

Comment: For that purpose why you don't use Jquery ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP, you only get to send a response once.

[image: HTTP example]

You can't send most of the response and then have the server keep working in the background to send more data later.

But that's ok, because your next idea is correct. The way to get around this problem is to use javascript to have the client send more requests and therefore get more data.

Personally, I use [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/). Let's take a look at how it works.

1. The user requests a page (an action).
2. The webserver delivers the response as a single HTML page.
3. An [Angular controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) loads additional data once the page has loaded.
4. Angular renders the data to the page.

[image: Angular and MVC]

You'll need to do some reading up on how AJAX works and what the best way to go about this is. My approach is a little more involved than a jQuery hack, but it's much more maintainable and organised (not a big jQuery fan).

Comment: Yea, I understand what you're saying. Let's say I want to return List<string>. I'll make another AJAX call and JSON response in MVC. How would those serialize? or what I'm trying to ask is, how would I display that List<string> on the webpage?

Comment: It depends if you use WebApi or not. WebApi will automatically convert any response you return into Json (or XML). Otherwise [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) can serialise .NET types into a Json string. You can then use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).